# Docker and OverlayFS

Tags: centos, mount, docker, overlayfs

I'm trying to learn about docker and the overlayFS, as suggest by the official website, I installed the last kernel:

```
4.8.11-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

and as [suggest by them](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#/configure-docker-with-the-overlayoverlay2-storage-driver) to ensure that overlay is good to go, I used:

```
 $ lsmod | grep overlay
```

But no success, it is because I don't have any FS or directory that is mounted with overlay, or should I do something else, like installing or loading the overlay kernel module? If so, can you suggest to me any tutorial to do so

For information I'm on:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

enable the kernel module with

> modprobe overlay

alternatively add overlay to systemd :

> echo "overlay" > /etc/modules-load.d/overlay.conf

and restart

Comment: I also modify /lib/systemd/system/docker.service by adding in [Service] ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --storage-driver=overlay2 , that means whenever i start/reboot docker it will use overlay2 as storage driver

Comment: Working fine with adding the new file `overlay.conf` for getting the *overlay* module to actually load on reboot.