# Why overlayfs increases boot time?

Tags: filesystems, overlayfs

Recently, I started using overlay filesystem. I'm using initram script (init=/sbin/myint) as described in Raspberry blog - [raspberry overlay](http://wiki.psuter.ch/doku.php?id=solve_raspbian_sd_card_corruption_issues_with_read-only_mounted_root_partition), yet, I noticed that it increases boot time significantly (about 10 seconds).

Is this increase in time happening because of mounting overlay filesystem?

**EDIT**:

I see that if I do the mount in init script instead of fstab file, then the additional time is reduced. Yet, I am not sure what's the difference.
in fstab:

```
/dev/mmcblock5      /app    ext4       defaults 0 0
overlay             /app    overlay defaults,lowerdir=/app,upperdir=/mnt/temp/upper2,workdir=/mnt/temp/work2
```

(/temp is mounted in initram script (init=/sbin/myint), see the link above)
in `/etc/local.d/01.start`
:

```
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/app,upperdir=/mnt/temp/upper2,workdir=/mnt/temp/work2 none /app
```

Comment: Are you loading overlay or overlay2? - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328978/docker-and-overlayfs.

Comment: I use overlay, not overlay2.

Comment: Try w/ overlay2 to see if that's the issue.

Comment: you could try comparing the output of `systemd-analyze blame` and/or `systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg`.  It might show which parts of the boot process happen more slowly / later on.

Comment: I made some progress , I see that if I mount the overlay in init script instead of fstab, the additional time is reduced. quite strange. any idea what's the difference ? The question was edited

Comment: I use openrc init scripts, so probably systemd-analyze won't help. Right?